# Extra content at the end of the document for xml data

Tags: java, xml, jsp

Getting following error when trying to returning xml data in jsp page:-
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 118 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

But view page source contains xml data.

```
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ModelArrayElement"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.FilterRules"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ModelsByDivisionRequest"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ModelsBySubdivisionRequest"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ModelConfigurationRequest"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.SideBySideComparison"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.SideBySideComparisonRequest"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.SideBySideComparisonGroup"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.AdvantageBasedComparison"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ConfigurationState"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.AdvantageBasedComparisonRequest"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.Trim"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.AdvantageComparison"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStreamWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.AutomotiveConfigCompareService4GPortType"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ConfigurationElement"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ReturnParameters"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.PriceSetting"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.MeasurementSystem"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.ConfigurationByStyleIdRequest"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="java.rmi.RemoteException"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.Configuration"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.Locale"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.AccountInfo"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.ui.Language.Languages"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.kp.configcompare3.OrderAvailability"%>
<%@page import="com.trilogy.forddirect.util.BuildMarketMode"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.Model"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.Trims.Year.Make"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.Trims.Year"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.compare.chrome.generated.TrimEnhanced"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.services.compare.chrome.ChromeStylesLoader"%>
<%@page import="com.forddirect.services.compare.chrome.*"%>
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Chrome SOAP requests</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function hideAll(){
    $('#baseId').hide();
    $('#otherIds').hide();
    $('#year').hide();
}

$(document)
    .ready(
            function() {
                    hideAll();
                    $('#baseId').show();

                $('select[name="requestType"]').change(function(){

                    if ($(this).val() == "style"){
                        hideAll();
                        $('#baseId').show();}
                    if ($(this).val() == "models"){
                        hideAll();
                        $('#year').show();}

                    if ($(this).val() == "simp"){
                        hideAll();
                        $('#baseId').show();
                        $('#otherIds').show();}

                    if ($(this).val() == "adv"){
                        hideAll();
                        $('#baseId').show();
                        $('#otherIds').show();}

                });
            });     
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

<form method="get" action="chromeCall.jsp">
<table><tr><td>
        Language :</td><td><input type="radio" id="lang" name="lang" value ="EN" checked="checked" />English<input type="radio" id="lang" name="lang" value ="FR" />French</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Locale :</td><td><input type="radio" id="locale" name="locale" value ="US" checked="checked" />US<input type="radio" id="locale" name="locale" value ="CA" />Canada</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Request Type: </td><td><select id="requestType" name="requestType">
            <option value="style">Style Details</option>
            <option value="models">Ford Models</option> 
            <option value="simp">Simple Comparison</option>
            <option value="adv">Advantage Comparison</option> 
        </select></td></tr></table>
        <table><tr id="year">
        <td>Year: </td><td><input type="text" id="year" name="year" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="baseId"><td>Base Style Id: </td><td><input type="text" id="baseStyleId" name="baseStyleId" value=""/></td></tr>
        <tr id="otherIds"><td>Competitor Ids (semiColon seperated): </td><td><input type="text" id="otherStyleId" name="otherStyleId" value=""/><br/></td></tr> 
        <!-- <label>Model Id</label><input type="text" id="model" value=""/><br/><input type="submit" id="getModel" value="Get Model Info"><br/>
        <label>Make Id</label><input type="text" id="make" value=""/><br/><input type="submit" id="getMake" value="Get Make Info"><br/>
        <label>Year</label><input type="text" id="year" value=""/><br/> -->
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="getResponse" value="Submit" />
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
    <%!private static final String COUNTRY_CANADA = "CA";
    private static final String defaultAccountNumber = "283766";
    private static final String defaultAccountSecret = "cc889e87936e4beb";
    private static final String defaultCountry = "US";
    private static final String defaultLanguage = "EN";
    private static final OrderAvailability defaultOrderAvailability = OrderAvailability.RETAIL;
    private static final String defaultRuleSet = "chromerules";
    private static AccountInfo currentAI = null;
    private static String lang = "EN";


    public ModelArrayElement getModelsByDivisionId(int divisionId, int modelYear, String language, OrderAvailability availability, AccountInfo ai) throws RemoteException, IOException {
    AutomotiveConfigCompareService4GPortType chromeJaxProxyService = ChromeServiceLocator.getChromeServicePort();
    List handlerList = ((BindingProvider) chromeJaxProxyService).getBinding().getHandlerChain();
    if (handlerList == null) {
        handlerList = new ArrayList();
    }
    SOAPLoggingHandler handler = new SOAPLoggingHandler();
    handlerList.add(handler);
    ((BindingProvider) chromeJaxProxyService).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerList);
        ModelsByDivisionRequest request = new ModelsByDivisionRequest();

        request.setAccountInfo(ai);
        FilterRules rules = new FilterRules();
        rules.setOrderAvailability(availability);
        request.setFilterRules(rules);
        request.setDivisionId(divisionId);
        request.setModelYear(modelYear);

        ModelArrayElement array = chromeJaxProxyService.getModelsByDivision(request);
        return array;
       }
    %>   
<%
           String lang = request.getParameter("lang") == null ? defaultLanguage : request.getParameter("lang");
           String locale = request.getParameter("locale") == null ? defaultCountry : request.getParameter("locale");
           String baseStyleId = request.getParameter("baseStyleId");
           String otherStyleId = request.getParameter("otherStyleId");
           String requestType = request.getParameter("requestType");
           String year = request.getParameter("year");
           currentAI = getAccountInfo(Languages.valueOf(lang), locale);
           }

           if (year!=null && "models".equals(requestType)) {
               ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  ModelArrayElement modelResponse = getModelsByDivisionId(13, Integer.valueOf(year), lang, defaultOrderAvailability, currentAI);
                  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ModelArrayElement.class);
                  Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                  marshaller.marshal(modelResponse, bytes);
                  String sb = new String(bytes.toByteArray());
                  String responseXML = sb.trim();
                   if(responseXML != null){
                       response.setContentType("text/xml");
                       out.println(responseXML.trim().substring("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".length())); 
                  }
           }
           if (request.getParameter("make") != null) {
            //make make request
           }
       %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `</body>` and `</html>` closing tag, but after that you have more code on the page.  Move that code inside the HTML body.